# SQL Server - Neutralizing a trigger during SP execution

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two tables, Orders and App.

App is a "helper" table which is populated according to Orders, and then passes the information on via web service to smart phones.

In order to populate App, we have created a parameterized stored procedure which runs at specific times, fluidly passing data from Orders to App.

But some updates to Orders are not caught by this stored procedure, so we were asked to create a trigger on Orders which executes this SP in these specific instances.  This, too, works fine.

The problem starts when updates arrive from smart phones to the table App.  The same parameterized SP runs "in reverse" to update the fields in Orders, and this works well - except that doing so can fire our supposedly selective trigger, resulting in redundant updates.  To demonstrate:

New row in Orders > SP > Row is written in App > App updated by application > SP > Corresponding row in Orders is updated > Trigger catches this update, firing the SP again.

In this chain, only the last step is a problem.

I have tried using DISABLE TRIGGER and ENABLE TRIGGER within the SP to avoid this problem, but this is risky business and certainly cannot be the best possible way.

The solution I'm working on now is by using a field which **is** updated during application updates to Orders, but is not updated at any other time.  For instance:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Orders.StartTime = getdate(),
    Orders.EndTime = CASE ... END,
    Orders.Unique_Field = X
WHERE Orders.ID = @APPID
```

In standard updates to Orders, the field Unique_Field is not included in any INSERT or UPDATE statements.  However, in some updates from App, this field may remain NULL.

My question is: What is the proper and safe way to tell my trigger to ignore any updates that arrive from my SP?

At present, my trigger looks like this:

```
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BUILDORDERCHECK AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @ORDERDATECHECK AS DATETIME
    DECLARE @ORDERNO AS INT
    DECLARE @CHECKER AS TINYINT
    SELECT @BUILDORDERCHECK = I.UpdateRecordDate,
    @ORDERDATECHECK = I.OrderDate,
    @ORDERNO = I.OrderNo,
    @CHECKER = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT Unique_Field FROM Inserted) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM Inserted I

    IF @BUILDORDERCHECK IS NOT NULL 
    AND @ORDERDATECHECK >= dateadd(day,-2,getdate())
    AND @CHECKER = 1
    -- Does not fire from BuildOrder
    -- Does not fire on tasks older than 2 days
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE [dbo].[Asp_Apper;1] 0, -- CallCode, DO NOT CHANGE
                                        1, -- Auto, 
                                        1, -- AOK, 
                                        0, -- CancelMsg, 
                                        0, -- TrailerNo
                                        1  -- RejectMsg
        END
END
```

@BUILDORDERCHECK and @ORDERDATECHECK work fine and behave as expected, but I need to find the right way to tell my trigger to check and see if Unique_Field was included in the update statement without being entangled by NULLS.  As I said, Unique_Field can be updated by the SP to a value of NULL, so simply checking for NULL doesn't work.

Thanking you all in advance for any thoughts...

EDIT: It's already been pointed out that this trigger seems to ignore cases where more than one row is updated, which is accurate.  Usually, we wouldn't build triggers like this; but in this case, updates to Orders are only ever row-by-row, and never in groups.  The only time that this isn't the case is when the SP runs, which we want to ignore anyway.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ...... FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic - you'll get one, arbitrary row and ignore all the other 24 rows. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: I should have included that in my original post: This trigger only ever fires from individual updates.  The program that updates Orders never updates more than one row at a time, which means that this trigger is always fired for one row **EXCEPT** when the SP runs.  In this instance, it may receive an update to one row or to many, but it is irrelevant as we don't want the trigger to fire at all in this instance.  Thank you for pointing out this flaw, though, since it's important for other people who might look at this later.

Comment: Are you basically trying to synchronise two tables based on a defined key? Do you actually have keys in these two tables that can tell you if a record already exists in the table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
Yes, it is a synchronization effort.  There is a shared value between the two tables which tells us if the record exists in one table or both.  (i.e. Only in Orders, or in Orders and App).  The basic setup is that a client-side user on a program edits Orders, which updates App, which is synchronized to another user's smart phone.  User2 can then update the record in App, and that update is then passed on to Order, where User1 can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [`CONTEXT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) and [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx), something like this:

In the trigger, add a check at the top that bails out if a particular context value is set:

```
IF ISNULL(CONTEXT_INFO(),0x0) = 0x49204C696B6520426967204275747473
   RETURN
```

And then in the (parts of) the stored procedures where you want to take actions that are ignored, just set that same value:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x49204C696B6520426967204275747473;
--Code that shouldn't cause the trigger to fire
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x0
```

Which keeps things nicely contained (unlike disabling the trigger which has *global* effects)

---

Also, I know you've already stated in comments that this trigger only needs to *work* for single row update but it would be an automatic failure in code review for me for any trigger that doesn't properly deal with multiple rows existing in `inserted` (or at the very least, *checks* the number of rows and gives a clear error message if the requirement of single row updates hasn't been fulfilled)

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course.  I have no arguments here.  Ideally, this trigger wouldn't even exist; it only exists because of a failure on the client-side program which we then had to resolve as quickly as possible.  The only function of this trigger is to execute the SP if the program failed to do so.  At that point, it is irrelevant if one row or a million were updated/inserted, as the SP logic handles all instances.  

Thank you very much, again, for pointing this out.  I much appreciate your help.